# javascript for numeric validation in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a javascript which works  well for numeric validation like below

```
function ValidateNum(e) { 
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 8)   { return true; }    
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))  return false;   
    return true; 
}
```

but we need to pass event like below to above javascript function

```
onkeypress="return ValidateNum(event)"
```

but in my project i have passed control to my old javascript function which was not working in all browsers like below

```
 onkeypress="ValidateNum(this)"
```

as i have now javascript which works well but it is not going to feasible to open all project and change calling method accordingly..

Comment: Search and replace? :)

Comment: Why are you looking at the charCode anyway? It's not very robust for validation as users can paste or drag and drop values. Look at the actual value instead. I'll guess that *this* is an input element, consider perhaps `if (/\D/.test(this.value)){ /* non-digit character entered */}`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i have other functions too for different works..please suggest better one

Comment: Better one: search and replace with regexp! :)